# In outlook event edit modal add a custom button

Tags: outlook, microsoft-graph-api, outlook-addin, outlook-web-addins, outlook-restapi

In outlook event Edit Modal add a custom button near to send and save button using outlook add-ins

Any possible to add custom button in that modal  , i want to trigger some function onClick the custom button in my outlook add-ins

Note :  My Add-ins developed by using javascript language

Any thoughts about this please share me?

Thanks in advance

Attached screenshot here

Answer (score 0):

No, it is not possible now. In Outlook when the user is composing a message, add-in commands added to the default tab appear on the Message tab. See [Add-in commands for Outlook](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/outlook/add-in-commands-for-outlook) for more information.

For other host applications you could use `insertAfter` and `insertBefore` elements to choose a custom location, read more about that in the [Position a custom tab on the ribbon](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/dev/add-ins/design/custom-tab-placement) article.